# Emacs org-mode: org to html conversion -- linking to section in a different page?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How can I link to a section of a separate page in org-mode and have it come out linked in the html? For instance, if in a file file.org, I have a label for section X:

```
** Section X
#+LABEL: sec:X
```

I can refer to this section with `[[sec:X][section X]]` within file.org. I can link to file.org with `[[file:file.org][link to file.html]]` from an external document (and will automatically be linked to the appropriate html file when published). But outside of this document, I can't refer to section X as `[[file:file.org#sec:X][link to section X of file.html]]` because the section label is converted to numbers (e.g., `sec-3_1`). So I would have to link to it as `[[file:file.html#sec-3_1][link to section X of file.html]]`, but that assumes I know that the `sec:X` label will be converted to `sec-3_1`...

(I am using the default functions used with `org-publish-project` for the conversion.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From: http://orgmode.org/manual/External-links.html#External-links

```
file:sometextfile::NNN                    file with line number to jump to
file:projects.org                         another Org file
file:projects.org::some words             text search in Org file
file:projects.org::*task title            heading search in Org file
```

**Edit:**
  Better use "CUSTOM_ID" Property like

```
  file1.org
  -------------

  * Section
    :PROPERTIES:
      :CUSTOM_ID: my_section_link_id
    :END:
```

Then in file2.org where you want to link to file1.org:Section

```
  * Sectoin In File2
    - Link to [[file:file1::my_section_link_id][Section]] in File1
```

I think there is a bug in orgmode 7.4 where if you use "file:file1::#my_section_link_id" it generates incorrect html link, but correct org link. If you use "file:file1::my_section_link_id" generates correct html link, but incorrect org link.

Comment: Thanks -- but the `file:projects.org::*task title` or `file:sometextfile::NNN` section links are lost (but remains linked to the page itself) when I use `org-publish-project`...